Jenkins active choice reactive parameter groovy script can't be worked
I set an active choice parameter named JOB_NAME in a jenkins job,it gets a view's all job name through the below groovy script :
import hudson.model.\*
def apps_name = \[\]
def view = Hudson.instance.getView("gcr-ibs")
for(item in view.getItems()){
if (item.getName() =\~ 'ci-.\*'){
apps_name.add(item.getName())
}
}
return apps_name

And then set an active choice reactive parameter job named tag,it's Referenced parameter is jobname which definded above.tag's groovy script as below,it can't be work.Can anyone point out where something is wrong,thanks very much.
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def tags = []
if (JOB_NAME) {
    def git_ssh_url = ""
    def project_id = ""

    // Step 1: get Git SSH URL from JOB_NAME
    node {
        scm_result = sh(script: "curl -X GET -s --user xxx.zeng:xxx http://jenkins-cn.intranet.local/job/${JOB_NAME}/configure | grep 'git@gitlab-'", returnStdout: true)
        echo "SCM Result: ${scm_result}"
        scm_result.eachMatch('git@gitlab.*\\\\.git\\"') {
            git_ssh_url = it.split('"')[0]
        }
    }
    echo "Git SSH URL: ${git_ssh_url}"
    
    if (!git_ssh_url) {
        error "Failed to retrieve Git SSH URL for job: ${JOB_NAME}"
    }

    // Step 2: get project id from Git SSH URL
    def projectname = git_ssh_url.split(':')[1].split('/').last() - '.git'
    def url = "http://gitlab-cn.intranet.local/api/v4/projects?search=${projectname}"
    node {
        def response = sh(script: "curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: E-xxx' '${url}'", returnStdout: true)
        echo "GitLab API Response: ${response}"
        def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
        def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(response)
        def exactMatchProject = json.find { it.name == projectname }
        if (exactMatchProject) {
            project_id = exactMatchProject.id
        } else {
            error "Project not found: ${projectname}"
        }
    }
    echo "Project ID: ${project_id}"

    // Step 3: get project tags from project id
    if (project_id) {
        def gitlabToken = 'E-xxx'
        def apiUrl = "http://gitlab-cn.intranet.local/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/repository/tags"
        node {
            try {
                def connection = new URL(apiUrl).openConnection()
                connection.setRequestProperty("PRIVATE-TOKEN", gitlabToken)
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
                
                def response2 = connection.inputStream.text
                echo "GitLab Tags Response: ${response2}"
                def json2 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response2)
                tags = json2.collect { it.name }.sort().reverse().take(12)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                println "Failed to retrieve tags from GitLab API: ${e.message}"
                error "Failed to retrieve tags from GitLab API: ${e.message}"
            }
        }
    } else {
        error "Failed to retrieve project ID for job: ${JOB_NAME}"
    }
}
return tags

I want to get gitlab project's tag, and the tag's value should be changed when the JOB_NAME's value changed.
